# Why .iml file is showing red in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Why the .iml file is showing red as shown in picture below? I remembered that it was not red originally.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaTiH.png)

Comment: Because it is not added to git and is not ignored in .gitignore?

Comment: In addition to the comment above, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html for more information

Answer (score 0):

If you have a VSC(Version Control System) set as GitHub, it is probably because it is not synchronized with the repository.